# How to save printer-friendly version of Ruby on Rails (Redmine) app as HTML?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, html, ruby-on-rails, redmine

E.g. there is the [issue list in Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues).

When I show print preview there only the table without headers will be shown and there will be a bit different style of the table (css for printer-friendly version?). I want to transfer this table into the MS Word document (don't want to save as PDF) for further modifying but

1. Copy and paste from Google Chrome's preview to MS Word does not save the style (only text is pasted). Also there is no ability to save as HTML that previewed page (only in PDF).
2. Internet Explorer does not provide an ability to copy the previewed page
3. Firefox also does not provide the ability
4. The recommendation to use Web Developer extension from [here](https://superuser.com/a/411989/434113) for Chrome was not helped for me: Redmine do not react on Display Print Styles checking.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution in Firefox: using the [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/) you may "Save HTML with Purge...". That's what I was looking for.